# Ansible return code error: 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, jboss

I am using Ansible to automate the installation, configuration and deployment of an application server which uses JBOSS, therefore I need to use the in-built jboss-cli to deploy packages.

This Ansible task is literally the last stage to run, it simply needs to check if a deployment already exists, if it does, undeploy it and redeploy it (to be idempotent).

Running the below commands manually on the server and checking the return code after each command works as expected, something, somewhere in Ansible refuses to read the return codes correctly!

```yaml
# BLAZE RMA DEPLOYMENT
- name: Check if Blaze RMA has been assigned to dm-server-group from a previous Ansible run
  shell: "./jboss-cli.sh --connect '/server-group=dm-server-group/deployment={{ blaze_deployment_version }}:read-resource()' | grep -q success"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ jboss_home_dir }}/bin"
  register: blaze_deployment_status
  failed_when: blaze_deployment_status.rc == 2
  tags: # We always need to check this as the output determines whether or not we need to undeploy an existing deployment.
    - skip_ansible_lint

- name: Undeploy Blaze RMA if it has already been assigned to dm-server-group from a previous Ansible run
  command: "./jboss-cli.sh --connect 'undeploy {{ blaze_deployment_version }} --all-relevant-server-groups'"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ jboss_home_dir }}/bin"
  when: blaze_deployment_status.rc == 0
  register: blaze_undeployment_status

- name: Deploy Blaze RMA once successfully undeployed
  command: "./jboss-cli.sh --connect 'deploy {{ jboss_deployment_dir }}/{{ blaze_deployment_version }} --server-groups=dm-server-group'"
  args:
    chdir: "{{ jboss_home_dir }}/bin"
  when: blaze_undeployment_status.rc == 0 or blaze_deployment_status.rc == 1
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second command contains a when clause. If it is skipped, ansible still registers the variable but there is no `rc` attribute in the data.

You need to take this into consideration when using the var in the next task. The following condition on last task should fix your issue.

```yaml
    when: blaze_undeployment_status.rc | default('') == 0 or blaze_deployment_status.rc == 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Zeitounator, that sounds promising and pretty obvious now you mention it! I'll update my code and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Also there is maybe the same as author situation, when you run `ansible --check`